# Converting between a multiline string and a TstringList

Tags: delphi, tstringlist, multilinestring

I have a multi-line string and I want to remove some lines from it. The TMemo component contains the necessary code to do this.

```
MyMemo:=TMemo.Create(nil);
try
   MyMemo.Text:=MyString;
   MyMemo.Lines.Delete(x); // lines I want to delete
   MyMemo.Lines.Delete(y);
   MyString:=MyMemo.Text;
finally
   MyMemo.Free;
end;
```

But it seems wrong to use a visual component to do basic conversions. Is there a different, but equally simple, way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Good thinking about avoiding visual components!

Comment: You should be aware, that the order of x and y matters. If x is smaller than y, you will delete line y-1 of the original list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the answer right in the question title - use a `TStringList`:

```
procedure MyProcedure(var MyString: string);
var
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Text := MyString;
    sl.Delete(x); // lines I want to delete
    sl.Delete(y);
    MyString := sl.Text;
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks I thought the Text was only applicable to the TMemo, not the TStrings within Tmemo

Comment: There's more - you might want to check `CommaText`, `StrictDelimiter` and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised that TStringlist itself has a Text property. So that answers my own question.

Comment: This adds nothing to Uli's answer. Can't you remove this and accept his answer?

Comment: I added this comment before I saw Uli's answer